# Is there an R function to normalize height in a pie chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, normalize

I'm trying to compare two pie chart from ggplot2,but when I try to graph it because of the big difference in length of the dataset It look very small.

I wanted the piechart divided by a category and group by another.

```
df %>% 
  count(category,group) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x="", y=n, fill=factor(group))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1)  +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  facet_wrap(~category)
```

I did the following to normalize their height.

```
Piechartdf <- df %>% 
  count(category,group) 

Piechart <- Piechart %>%
      mutate(proportion = case_when(
        Type=="category1" ~ n/sum(Piechart[which(Piechart$Type == "category1"), 3]),
        Type=="category2" ~ n/sum(Piechart[which(Piechart$Type == "category2"), 3])
      ))
```

Then in the first one, I just chance n for proportion, Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide sample data by posting the output of `dput(df)`?

Comment: Your approach is good - to calculate and plot proportions rather than counts, but your `dplyr` code is clunky. If you share some data as r2evans suggests, we may be able to help.

Comment: structure(list(X = 36:51, category = c("category2", "category2", 
"category2", "category2", "category2", "category2", "category2", 
"category2", "category2", "category2", "category2", "category1", 
"category1", "category1", "category1", "category1"), group = c(30L, 
40L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 20L, 30L, 30L, 40L, 30L, 30L, 50L, 30L, 
60L, 40L)), row.names = 36:51, class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try

```
df %>% 
  count(category,group) %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(n = n/sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x="", y=n, fill=factor(group), group = category)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1)+
  coord_polar("y", start=0)  +
  facet_wrap(~category)
```

[image]